# How to optimize layout performance for events within the child component?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a component with such design. this is not code, just a high-level representation of the component structure.

```
Container {
   child1 : {

   },
   child2 : {

   },
   child3 : {

   },
   ...
}

Child component : {
   event that will cause layout update
}
```

Now the page become very slow whenever the event triggered in the child components. Since the event code is written within component, I'm not sure how can I make use of suspendLayout().

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [batchLayout](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.html#method-batchLayouts). This will suspend all layouts until your function is done.

```
Container {
   child1 : {

   },
   child2 : {

   },
   child3 : {

   },
   ...
}

    Child component : {     
        // event that will cause layout update
        event: function() {        
            const me = this;

            Ext.batchLayouts(function() {
                // Your code            
            }, me);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But the problem here is the event will add some component to the child component which trigger layout run. and there are multiple child. Events are ASYNC. I can suspendLayout at the first event trigger, but how can I tell which is the final event so that i can resumeLayout() at the final one.

After a day of trying, I end up adding a delayTask with 100ms delay at the container level, then everytime the event call, I call a function which cancel the task and restart it. So, the last task will execute Ext.resumeLayouts(true);

I'm not sure is there a better solution. :)

Comment: Is this a scenario where on each event you do a call to e.g. your server and  in regards to the return you add components to your container?

I would assume that if you have async events that maybe you can use a Promise. (There is also Ext.Promise and Ext.deferred)... Sometimes I had cases in the past where I also had to use a delayed task because there were several actions that were similar and I didn't know how often and when the last action is triggered so I had to use that aswell.